# How to determine the parameters/inputs of an undocumented API (ESPN Sports API)

Tags: python

I am becoming familiar with Python and API's and am doing so by using  API for sports.

In my example,

The API link I am using is: `http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard` which returns all the data from this webpage **https://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard**. This is the top 25 games showing that is happening that week.

However, I want to see what "SEC" games are playing this week,  so on the ESPN website I filter by "SEC" games and webpage is now this :
[www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/group/8](http://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/group/8) . Now, I want to return the same values by calling the API but I need to know the right parameters so it only returns the SEC games.

I have tried:

```
site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard?group=8
```

but that just returns the same values from the first API call (the top 25 games)

How can way to determine the correct "parameters" that go into this URL or syntax so that I can determine the right way to call the ESPN API to return the SEC games?

Comment: hmm, i haven't worked with undocumented APIs before. so is this a public facing API, or more of an internal one?

Comment: im not a 100% sure. it looks to be public. many people use it.

Comment: Found this: https://gist.github.com/akeaswaran/b48b02f1c94f873c6655e7129910fc3b

Comment: yeah I used that too. It doesnt say the params for my call unfortunately.

Comment: It describes them at the beginning, where it says "Latest scores". There are two params: `calendar` and `dates`.

Comment: If there's no documentation or public source code for the API, there's no easy way to figure out what the parameters are.

Comment: there should be a way to filter by group, id imagine.

Comment: So if there isn’t any docs and I cannot believe that, maybe contact the ESPN support or use another API

Comment: the parameter here should be `groups` not `group`:  `https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard?groups=8`

Answer (score 1):

So your issue is that you have ?group=8 in your API Url. Your call needs to be ?groups=8.

Example:
https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard?groups=8

Example with Week filter added:
 https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/college-football/scoreboard?groups=8&week=5

The root for all of the API calls for College Football starts with this URL below. If you wanted to work with other sports remove everything after sports, and it will list all of the data endpoints available
https://sports.core.api.espn.com/v2/sports/football/leagues/college-football/
https://sports.core.api.espn.com/v2/sports/

*** TIP ***
You can add ?limit=1000 or &limit=1000 to any endpoint Url call so that you won't have to page through results that often.

I use these endpoints to help me keep my CFB Data Warehouse updated for http://www.cfbdata.co